# How do I display xml code samples from a razor view?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to display code samples to my webpage and the razor view engine is treating the tags as code.

Example:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>` does not appear on the page.

How do I stop this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html.Encode and Html.Raw should do the trick with XML...

```
   @Html.Encode(Html.Raw("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>"))
```

ETA: Had that a bit wrong.

Comment: When I try that, first, it doesn't like the double quotes within the tag.  Then, if I replace those, it doesn't appear on the page.  I inspect it in the browser and it shows it commented out <!-- (xml code here) --!>